# Is this the correct way to draw on a UIImageview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to make an app that draw on screen following my finger. I took pieces from several websites and manage to get it done.  [screenshot app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h78Qs.jpg)

The app is working , I can choose different colors and line is following my finger. Only thing is that when i use it on a real device (iphone SE and Xs Max) after a bunch of lines my app crash with the message iOS terminate on memory.
this is not happening with the simulator. I am not experienced enough to use instruments. Any idea what can cause this ?

maybe something wrong in the function :

`func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {`

Or has a iPhone just not enough memory to draw on a full screen, then I am wasting my time searching for a solution that has no solution?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var UIImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var colourInUse: UILabel!
    var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
     var red: CGFloat = 0.0
     var green: CGFloat = 0.0
     var blue: CGFloat = 0.0
     var brushWidth: CGFloat = 2.0
     var opacity: CGFloat = 1.0
     var swiped = false

     let colors: [(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat)] = [
       (0, 0, 0),
       (105.0 / 255.0, 105.0 / 255.0, 105.0 / 255.0),
       (1.0, 0, 0),
       (0, 0, 1.0),
       (51.0 / 255.0, 204.0 / 255.0, 1.0),
       (102.0 / 255.0, 204.0 / 255.0, 0),
       (102.0 / 255.0, 1.0, 0),
       (160.0 / 255.0, 82.0 / 255.0, 45.0 / 255.0),
       (1.0, 102.0 / 255.0, 0),
       (1.0, 1.0, 0),
       (1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
     ]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        UIImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tempImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        colourInUse.text = "Black"
    }


    @IBAction func pencilPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

      var index = sender.tag ?? 0
      if index < 0 || index >= colors.count {
        index = 0
      }

      (red, green, blue) = colors[index]

      if index == colors.count - 1 {
        opacity = 1.0
      }


      }


      override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
          swiped = false
        if let touch = touches.first {
                lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
             }
      }

     override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
         swiped = true
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let currentPoint = touch.location(in: view)
            drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)
             lastPoint = currentPoint
        }
    }

        override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

            if !swiped {
            drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
          }

          // Merge tempImageView into mainImageView
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(UIImage.frame.size)
            UIImage.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: 1.0)
            tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height), blendMode: CGBlendMode.normal, alpha: opacity)
          UIImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

          tempImageView.image = nil
        }





        func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

          UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0)
          let drawContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))

            drawContext?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
            drawContext?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

            drawContext?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
            drawContext?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)

            drawContext?.setStrokeColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
            drawContext?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
            drawContext?.strokePath()

            tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
          tempImageView.alpha = opacity

          UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        }

    }
```

Comment: try using Custom UIView subclass with CAShapeLayer.

Comment: @Cosmos Thx  i started with your solution, found a good tutorial on that : [link](https://www.appcoda.com/bezier-paths-introduction/)

Comment: Another tip and trick is that you should be doing less amount of work in drawing code. Here, you are doing a lot of work in a 16 milliseconds time frame. If you would like to know more, you can search for "Quartz 2D programming guide" and related CoreGraphics articles.

Comment: @Cosmos Thx i will look into that also, but today not much time anymore.

Comment: @Cosmos... i managed to get it work without crashing and my memory stays low <20 mB instead of my original program where the memory get up to 1GB. Thanks alot. The Custom UIView subclass with CAShapeLayer did the trick.